# Why an iOS application based on OpenGL will be rejected on review process?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, app-store, metal

I try to find link to a document, where Apple writes that all new applications can't be based on OpenGL.
I know that OpenGL is deprecated.
Can someone to show some document where is written that I can't publish new applications with OpenGL ES (all new applications with OpenGL will are rejected)?
I need a link to a document, not a story about rejection some application with OpenGL.

Comment: Are you _assuming_ that those rejections will happen, or has your app been rejected for this reason?

Comment: Yes, I assume that. But I need proof of my opinion and can't find it :(

Comment: OpenGL is not yet deprecated for iOS, so I would assume you can submit new apps just fine…

Comment: OpenGL was definitely deprecated on iOS in 2018 with iOS 12: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opengles/. While I sorta vaguely remember them laying out plans to start rejecting over it/drop support for it entirely back then, I also can't find any documentation about those plans. Maybe they dropped their plans to formally drop it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can confirm that there are no problems publishing an app with the **OpenGL API** at this time. This may soon change though.